# Regular Expression to find last folder in a path

Tags: regex, path, expression

I would like to find the last folder in a path. Ex:

```
G:\DATA1\DATA2\DATA3\DATA4\my target\file.xxx
```

I need to extract **my target**. I tried `(^.*\\)(.*\\)` but the result is my `target\`. Someone can fix it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the power of greedy operator along with capturing group.

```
.*\\([^\\]+)\\
```

**OR**

Use the same regex but get out of the last backslash from the second capturing group.

```
.*\\(.*)\\
```

Get the string you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qA9eZ1/1)

Comment: And if you are on a system with forward slashes instead of backslashes: `.*\/([^\/]+)\/`

Comment: This one worked for my case, thanks a lot